# Joining Table A and B to get elements of both

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have two tables:

Table 'bookings':

```
  id    |    date   | hours
--------------------------
   1    | 06/01/2016 |    2
   1    | 06/02/2016 |    1
   2    | 06/03/2016 |    2
   3    | 06/03/2016 |    4
```

Table 'lookupCalendar':

```
date 
-----
06/01/2016
06/02/2016
06/03/2016
```

I want to join them together so that I have a date for each booking so that the results look like this:

Table 'results':

```
  id    |    date   | hours
--------------------------
   1    | 06/01/2016 |    2
   1    | 06/02/2016 |    1
   1    | 06/03/2016 |    0  <-- Added by query
   2    | 06/01/2016 |    0  <-- Added by query
   2    | 06/02/2016 |    0  <-- Added by query
   2    | 06/03/2016 |    2
   3    | 06/01/2016 |    0  <-- Added by query
   3    | 06/02/2016 |    0  <-- Added by query
   3    | 06/03/2016 |    4
```

I have tried doing a cross-apply, but that doesn't get me there, neither does a full join. The `FULL JOIN` just gives me nulls in the id column and the cross-apply gives me too much data.

Is there a query that can give me the `results` table above?

**More Information**

It might be beneficial to note that I am doing this so that I can calculate an average hours booked over a *period of time*, not just the number of records in the table.

Ideally, I'd be able to do

```
SELECT AVG(hours) AS my_average, id
FROM bookings
GROUP BY id
```

But since that would just give me a count of the records instead of the count of the days I want to cross apply it with the dates. Then I think I can just do the query above with the `results` table.

Comment: Why are you adding 2 records for 6/1, 2 records for 6/2 and 1 record for 6/3 ... they're added by what query?  What is the logic by which those 5 records would be added to the 4 records from the bookings table?

Comment: That's what I want to do, not what I am doing. If I knew how to do it, I wouldn't have asked the question ;)

Comment: Was asking for an explanation of the logic in english, not t-sql.  Nevermind though, hopefully one of the interpretations below is correct for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select i.id, c.date, coalesce(b.hours, 0) as hours
  from lookupCalendar c
  cross join (select distinct id from bookings) i
  left join bookings b
    on b.id = i.id
   and b.date = c.date
 order by i.id, c.date
```

Comment: That is brilliant. Very nice - I knew it had to be something like this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select c.date, b.id, isnull(b.hours, 0)
from lookupCalendar c
left join bookings b on b.date = c.date
```

`LookupCalendar` is your main table because you want the bookings against each date, irrespective of whether there was a booking on that date or not, so a `left join` is required.

I am not sure if you need to include `b.id` to solve your actual problem though. Wouldn't you just want to get the total number of hours booked against each date like this, to then calculate the average?:

```
select c.date, sum(isnull(b.hours, 0))
from lookupCalendar c
left join bookings b on b.date = c.date
group by c.date
```

Comment: Very close. However, I think that the one remaining problem is that `b.id` will return null in some cases.

Comment: Yes, not sure if I understood your second question correctly, but if you want to calculate the average hours booked over the three dates, do you care about the `id` at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can try joining all the combinations of IDs and dates and left joining the data;

```
WITH Booking AS (SELECT * 
                  FROM (VALUES
                      ( 1  , '06/01/2016',   2  )
                    , ( 1  , '06/02/2016',   1  )
                    , ( 2  , '06/03/2016',   2  )
                    , ( 3  , '06/03/2016',   4  )
                    ) x (id, date, hours)
  )
  , lookupid AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT id FROM Booking
  )
  , lookupCalender AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT date FROM Booking
  )
  SELECT ID.id, Cal.Date, ISNULL(B.Hours,0) AS hours
  FROM  lookupid id
  INNER JOIN lookupCalender Cal
  ON 1 = 1
  LEFT JOIN Booking B
  ON id.id = B.id
  AND Cal.date = B.Date
  ORDER BY ID.id, Cal.Date
```

Comment: To find the average, it might be simplier to;  `SELECT id, 1.0*SUM(hours) / (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT date) FROM lookupCalenda)  FROM Booking GROUP BY id`